# Set up sign-in with a Google account using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C and fetch profile picture

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory, gmail, profile

How can I fetch a profile picture from Google identity provider using Azure Active directory B2C?

I've successfully implemented Sign In with Google Account in Azure B2C following the procedure described in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-goog-idp).
but I am not sure how to fetch the profile picture.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/) to fetch the profile picture.

The required permissions:

[image]

Request:

```
Get https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id}/photo/$value
```

> Note: for the email account, you could only use the object id, cannot
>   use the username.

[image]
Response:
[image]

For the details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-beta).